# Swap Cursor Column Order?

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a procedure that returns a two column cursor of `NAME (VARCHAR)` and `ID (INTEGER)`. A different component requires a cursor of the exact same data, but with the order of `ID` followed by `NAME`.

So I'm wrapping up this procedure with another procedure, and I'm about to fetch from one cursor into a temp cursor with different column order, but that seems extremely wasteful.

Is there a cleaner/more efficient way for me to return a new cursor with the columns swapped?

Comment: What is the benefit of fetching from the first cursor in this case?  If the query used to open the first cursor contains business logic that you don't want to duplicate, I'd tend to create a view that implements the logic and have both pieces of code call that view.

Comment: A pipelined table function should be able do this reasonably efficiently, if you really can't change the existing interfaces.

Comment: Thanks. I can't change either as the first procedure is used in several systems, and the new one is going into a system with very specific needs.